# reschedule a sidekiq job from within perform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Is there a way to check a condition inside `perform` in a Sidekiq worker, and to reschedule the job in a different time (and stop executing the job)?

```
def perform

 if is_it_summer_yet?
   Bear.wake_em_up
 else
   # reschedule to perform in a few hours
 end

end
```

this is a simple example, but in my use case there are a lot of calculations and network calls for that condition, so I can't do it externally

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
def perform
  if is_it_summer_yet?
    Bear.wake_em_up
  else
    self.class.perform_in(1.hour)
  end
end
```

Comment: looks suspiciously simple

Answer (score 1):

CAUSION!  remember **return**  after *self.class.perform_in()*

I got serious problem in production env.

Comment: what problems did you get?

Comment: I would imagine a fork bomb.